# How to serialize Java.choose() in Frida JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, serialization, frida

I am not very proficient in JavaScript, hence facing some trouble in Frida JS API. All I can see Java.choose() is async; meaning that it enumerates all the live instances of the class `className`. However, the caveat is , it can return early even before the enumeration finishes. In my application, I require the function (F) calling `Java.choose()` return only at the end of enumeration. Because inside `onMatch()`, I am populating a list which needs to be fully populated before `F` returns to its caller. Google says I can use `Promise` or `await`  to serialize it. With my limited JS-fu, I failed to make any of the solutions work. Can a JS guru please step in and throw some snippet to save this poor soul?

Also, another concern is, I don't come from a functional (event-driven?) programming background. Is serializing an async function used as the last resort in JS world?

```
const getObjectInstances = function(argument){ 

    searchHeap(argument)
        .then(function(class_instances){
            console.log(class_instances);
           //return class_instances;
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log("error");
        }) 
}

const searchHeap = function(cls_name){
    var class_instances = [];
    Java.choose(cls_name, {
        onMatch:function(instance){
            console.log("Found instance" + instance);
            class_instances.push(instance);
        },
        onComplete:function() {
            console.log("search done");
        }
    });
}
```

What I want is `searchHeap()` to return only when enumeration finishes. Otherwise, the caller receives an incomplete `class_instances[]` list. How hard is to make this work? Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the following

```
var class_instances;
    Java.choose(cls_name, {
        onMatch:function(instance){
            console.log("Found instance" + instance);
            class_instances = instance;
        },
        onComplete:function() {
            console.log("search done");
        }
    });
```

then you can call any method of that class name. For example if it had a function named `status` it will be possible to call it `instance.status()`.

The instances can be looked in the structure of the apk. I use [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) for this. You might also want to try [MobSF](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) a framework that has integrated Frida and other useful tools making possible dynamic and static analysis.